# Slash and integer from attr concatenation won't create an icon code

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, attr

I am trying to pass the fa icon code without the slash like this:

```
<div data-icon="f00c"></div>
```

And then on CSS add the slash `\` in front of the `data-icon` like this:

```
content: '\\' attr(data-icon);
```

The problem is this will print `\f00c` and not the icon. It will work of course if I just do:

```
content: '\f00c';
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: and why you don't want to add the slash?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behaviour is, that the *stylesheet parser* in css detects the backslashes in a appearing css string and transforms the following four chars as an hex-value into one UTF8 char.

By adding a '\' before the attribute value you just concatenating a backslash to the attribute chars. CSS provides no function to transform hex values as strings (e.g. given by `attr`) to a char in runtime.

There is no other way, than to handle it on the HTML side by escaping the hex-values there using e.g. `&#xXXXX;`:

```css
content: attr(data-icon);
```

```html
<div data-icon="&#xf00c;"></div>
<!-- or adding the unicode directly, if it's an utf8 document -->
<div data-icon=""></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I already use `&#xf00c;` but because this is part of a wordpress theme I was wondering if its possible to add the `&#x` or `\\` part on the css. That way users would simply add a number (which would be easier for them). Anyways, I guess that's impossible. Thanks!

Comment: with the current version of CSS (which is CSS3) there is no way. CSS is sadly not a clever programming language, that can do stuff like that.